Attach Curve hair is suddenly missing after adding "interpolated hair curves" and changing some settings


PC Specs
Geforce 4060ti
Ryzen 9 7900
Blender 4.2LTS
Summary
After I Added another  hair in sculpt mode,(already added some hair curves and "interpolated hair curves")
"interpolated hair curves" was gone.
Details
I made Hair with "Empty hair" of ⇧ Shift + A.(not particle distance )
and I finished hair to some extent in sculpt mode and added  "interpolated hair curves".
Then went to weight paint mode of sculpted mesh, (in my Blender project, the name is "Hair")
added new vertex group and painted it as a whole.(the vertex group name is "whole")
Finally, I changed number to "whole" in "Density mask" of  "interpolated hair curves".
And it was working ,but when I added some hair in sculpt mode to fix shape,
"interpolated hair curves" was disappeared then I tried to fix this but hair is still gone.
This problem is occurred in "body_Hair" in the image. Although I can see "body_Hair" when I select, I can't see anything when I don't select even can't see original one.
The other image that is selected hair called "Front" is working everything.
The both settings are same except for Density Mask name and Density number.
So, could you tell me how I fix this?
